# How to refactor parts of an EF select

Tags: entity-framework

Let's say I have the following EF code:

```
context.Employees.Select(e => e
{
    FullName = e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName,
    StartDate = e.StartDate,
    ... // Grab other data
};
```

Now maybe I notice that I construct the full name in multiple places, but would like in centralized. Is it possible to refactor this?

If I make it a method or a Func, I get EF errors, because it can't translate it into SQL.

NOTE: This is a simple example, assume it can get much more complicated with "Select"s, "Where"s, whatever in the assignment, so adding a ToList and then running additional code would be suboptimal and does not fit the definition of refactoring since I would have to change functionality and not just make it more maintainable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use the `AsExpandable` method from [LinqKit](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqkit.aspx):

```
Expression<Func<Employee,string>> fullName = e => e.FirstName + " " + e.LastName;
context.Employees.AsExpandable().Select(e => e
{
    FullName = fullName.Compile().Invoke(e),
    StartDate = e.StartDate,
    ... // Grab other data
};
```

From the linked article:

> Compile is an inbuilt method in the Expression class. It converts the
>   Expression into a plain Func which
>   satisfies the compiler. Of course, if this method actually ran, we'd
>   end up with compiled IL code instead of an expression tree, and LINQ
>   to SQL or Entity Framework would throw an exception. But here's the
>   clever part: Compile never actually runs; nor does LINQ to SQL or
>   Entity Framework ever get to see it. The call to Compile gets stripped
>   out entirely by a special wrapper that was created by calling
>   AsExpandable, and substituted for a correct expression tree.

Alternatively, you could look into creating an [Model Defined Function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456857.aspx) with Entity Framework. There's also the [Microsoft.Linq.Translations](http://damieng.com/blog/2009/06/24/client-side-properties-and-any-remote-linq-provider) library if you want to define a FullName property on the Employee class itself.

Answer (score 0):

I think the better centralized way to do it in the entity class itself. You can add ReadOnly property to your entity class which should be `NotMapped` to the database to return required formatted data.

```
Public class Employee
{
//...

public string fullName{get { return  FirstName + " " + LastName;}}
}
```