# Generating parts of select EF Core expression in a function

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have a lot of queries in my application that use a subquery to compute a flag, which is often needed, as this:

```cs
var query = from cmds in _context.Set<Cmds>()
// ...
select new {
    cmd,
    // 
    Reco = (
        from sc in _context.Set<SalCand>()
        where sc.SourceDb == salarie.SourceDb && sc.CodeSala == salarie.Code && sc.Libelle == cmd.NomCli
            && sc.TypeListe == "RE" && sc.IdProfil == 3
            && ((Natures1.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 1) ||
                (Natures2.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 2) ||
                (Natures3.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 3))
        select 1
    ).Any(),
};
```

Thi generates :

```sql
SELECT [m4].[Code], -- lots of columns 
    CASE WHEN EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM [salcand] AS [m7]
        WHERE [m7].[SourceDb] = [m4].[SourceDb] AND [m7].[CodeSala] = [m4].[Code] 
            AND [m7].[Libelle] = [m0].[NomCli] AND [m7].[TypeListe] = N'RE'
            AND [m7].[IdProfil] = 3 AND (
                ([m0].[Nature] = N'I' AND [m7].[IdSProfil] = 1) OR
                ([m0].[Nature] IN (N'A', N'N') AND [m7].[IdSProfil] = 2) OR
                ([m0].[Nature] IN (N'S', N'P') AND [m7].[IdSProfil] = 3))
    ) THEN CAST(1 AS bit)
    ELSE CAST(0 AS bit)
END AS [Reco], -- a few more computed flags/values
FROM [cmds] AS [m]
INNER JOIN [cmd] AS [m0] ON -- ...
INNER JOIN [salarie] AS [m4] ON -- ...
```

I would like to generate it in a function, for obvious reasons; I tried to generate an `IQueryable`:

```cs
public static IQueryable<int> Reco(RecrutementDbContext ctx, Salarie salarie, Cmd cmd)
{
    return (from sc in ctx.Set<SalCand>()
            where sc.SourceDb == salarie.SourceDb && sc.CodeSala == salarie.Code && sc.Libelle == cmd.NomCli
                  && sc.TypeListe == "RE" && sc.IdProfil == 3
                  && ((Natures1.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 1) ||
                      (Natures2.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 2) ||
                      (Natures3.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 3))
            select 1).AsExpandable();
}
```

to call it in queries like this:

```
Reco = GestionUtils.Reco(_context, salarie, cmd).Any()
```

But EF Core cannot translate it at runtime :

> fail: NEROLIRecrutement.Controllers.ContratsController[0]
>
> Got error The LINQ expression 'GestionUtils.Reco(
> ctx: ___context_4,
> salarie: NavigationTreeExpression
> Value: EntityReference: Salarie
> Expression: ti8.Outer.Inner,
> cmd: NavigationTreeExpression
> Value: EntityReference: Cmd
> Expression:   ti8.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Outer.Inner)
> .Any()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Is there a way to return something that can be translated at runtime ?

I also tried (inspired by [How to refactor parts of an EF select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13387937/how-to-refactor-parts-of-an-ef-select))

```cs
public static Expression<Func<Salarie, Cmd, bool>> Reco1(RecrutementDbContext ctx)
{
    return (salarie, cmd) => (
                from sc in ctx.Set<SalCand>()
                where sc.SourceDb == salarie.SourceDb && sc.CodeSala == salarie.Code && sc.Libelle == cmd.NomCli
                    && sc.TypeListe == "RE" && sc.IdProfil == 3
                    && ((Natures1.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 1) ||
                        (Natures2.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 2) ||
                        (Natures3.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 3))
                select 1
            ).Any();
}

// called as:
Reco = GestionUtils.Reco1(_context).Compile().Invoke(salarie, cmd),


public static Expression<Func<RecrutementDbContext, Salarie, Cmd, bool>> Reco2()
{
    return (ctx, salarie, cmd) => (
                from sc in ctx.Set<SalCand>()
                where sc.SourceDb == salarie.SourceDb && sc.CodeSala == salarie.Code && sc.Libelle == cmd.NomCli
                    && sc.TypeListe == "RE" && sc.IdProfil == 3
                    && ((Natures1.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 1) ||
                        (Natures2.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 2) ||
                        (Natures3.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 3))
                select 1
            ).Any();
}

// called as:

Reco = GestionUtils.Reco2().Compile().Invoke(_context, salarie, cmd),
```

The `Reco1` fails at runtime with error:

> There is already an open DataReader associated with this Connection which must be closed first

The `Reco2` fails at runtime with error

> The client projection contains a reference to a constant expression of 'System.Func<NEROLIRecrutement.RecrutementDbContext, NEROLIRecrutement.Models.Salarie, NEROLIRecrutement.Models.Cmd, bool>' through the instance method 'Invoke'. This could potentially cause a memory leak; consider making the method static so that it does not capture constant in the instance. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2103067 for more information and examples.

@heringer's suggestion fails too :

```cs
public static Expression<Func<IQueryable<SalCand>, Salarie, Cmd, bool>> Reco()
{
    return (sc_, salarie, cmd) => (
        from sc in sc_
        where sc.SourceDb == salarie.SourceDb && sc.CodeSala == salarie.Code && sc.Libelle == cmd.NomCli
            && sc.TypeListe == "RE" && sc.IdProfil == 3
            && ((Natures1.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 1) ||
                (Natures2.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 2) ||
                (Natures3.Contains(cmd.Nature) && sc.IdSProfil == 3))
        select 1
    ).Any();
}

// Called as :

Reco = GestionUtils.Reco().Compile().Invoke(_context.Set<SalCand>(), salarie, cmd),
```

> Got error The LINQ expression 'DbSet()' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

Thanks

Comment: Are you calling Reco1 from a place where you already call ctx.Set<SalCand>()? Maybe you could try passing the DbSet (sc) as a parameter to Reco1. Or better: pass a IQueryable.

Comment: If you clean up the query you probably won't have to use a function to construct it. There's no reason to call `Natures1.Contains(cmd.Nature) ` 3 times. If you want to check whether `sc.IdSProfil ` is in a list of values, use `idValues.Contains(sc.IdSProfil)`. This transates to `sc.IdSProfil IN (value1, valu2,....).`. Finally, what's the point of `select 1` ? What's the actual query you tried to execute?

Comment: Keep in mind (that's a *very* strong suggestion) that EF is an ORM, not embedded SQL. LINQ is the ORM's query language, not embedded SQL. An ORM's job is to give the impression of working with in-memory objects instead of tables and rows. It seems you tried to emulate an `EXISTS (....)` clause, putting one EF query inside another. What are you trying to do?

Comment: I totally want `Exists (...)`, as I tries to compute some kind of dynamic flags